# Idl readcol function, using delimeter without syntax error

Tags: delimiter, idl-programming-language

Im trying to use idl to read a file, so im using the readcol command. However, in my file i use | as a delimiter, but continually get syntax errors. Heres my latest attempt:

```
readcol,'kcorrins.txt',uband, gband, rband, iband, zband, $
   ubanderr, gbanerr, rbanderr, ibanderr, zbanderr, adjredshift, $
   SKIPLINE=1, DELIMITER=|
```

could someone post an example of the proper syntax for using the delimiter in this way?

Answer (score 1):

You need to quote the delimiter:

```
readcol,'kcorrins.txt',uband, gband, rband, iband, zband, $
  ubanderr, gbanerr, rbanderr, ibanderr, zbanderr, adjredshift, $
  SKIPLINE=1, DELIMITER='|'
```